# type casting in C++

Tags: c++

I'm fairly new to C++ and I'm not sure how to type cast correctly or rather I'm unsure of how to cast parameters in this method that potentially needs a type cast.

I have a function getRadius

```
double Circle_getRadius(Circle* _this)
{
    return _this->radius;
}
```

and I want to use the this method in a getArea method as follows

```
double Circle_area(Shape* _this)
{
    const double PI = 3.1415927;
    double radi = Circle_getRadius;
    return PI *  radi * radi;
}
```

I get an error under Circle_getRadius saying "Error: a value of type "double(*)(Circle*_this)" cannot be used to initialize an entity of type "double". What does this mean?

I've tried this as well with an error

```
double Circle_area(Shape* _this)
{
    const double PI = 3.1415927;
    return PI *  radius * radius;
}
```

Where radius is getting the error "Error:identifier "radius" is undefined. Any suggestions?

Comment: "Any suggestions?" Learn C++ from a book.

Comment: `double radi = Circle_getRadius(_this);` I assume you're from a python background? It looks like you're trying to use class-member functions but decided not to?

Comment: I'm not sure if the use of a parameter called `_this` is a good sign...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The ACTUAL solution to this is to have a class hierarchy where a virtual function `GetArea` knows how to calculate the size of the object itself.

It makes no sense to get the `radius` on a square or a triangle, and calculating the area of a circle, triangle or square are all different.

```
class Shape
{
  public:
   virtual double GetArea() = 0; 
};

class Circle: public Shape
{ 
  private:
    double radius;
  public:
    Circle(double r) : radius(r) {}
    double GetArea() { return radius * radius * PI; }
};

class Square : public Shape
{
  private:
    double side;
  public:
    Square(double s) : side(s) {}
    double GetArea() { return side * side; }
};
```

... I'll let you figure out how to do a triangle, rectangle, ellipsis, etc.

And we can then do something like this:

```
Shape& x = Circle(3.5)
Shape& y = Square(5);

cout << x.GetArea() << " " << y.GetArea() << endl;
```

Your code looks a bit like you are expecting C++ to operate like Python or PHP, where the function calls on an object gets resolved at runtime. In C++, functions must exist for the object when you compile the code.

Comment: This is probably the only sane answer. +1.

Answer (score 5):

This has nothing to do with casting. (You shouldn't generally be casting anything anyway.)

You forgot the function call parentheses and the argument(s):

```
double radi = Circle_getRadius(_this);
//                            ^^^
```

(The function name by itself is also a value, but its type is a function pointer type, namely the type `double (*)(Circle *)`.)

This assumes that a `Shape*` is convertible to a `Circle*`, which seems unlikely. You *could* cast one to the other (by saying `static_cast<Circle*>(_this)`, and assuming that `Circle` derives (non-virtually) from `Shape`), but as I said, you shouldn't generally be doing this and it would probably not be correct.

Comment: I did not realize this wasn't casting, sorry. I'm just confused on how I'm supposed to get this variable into this method. It seems that the getRadius isn't working for what everyone has commented, "Error: type name is not allowed". Is there a way to get a pointer to the variable within this method?

Comment: @Phirip: Please post the actual code that causes the error, as well as the error message.

Comment: `double Circle_area(Shape* _this)
{
 const double PI = 3.1415927;
 double radi = Circle_getRadius(Circle* _this);
 return PI *  radi * radi;
}`
Under Circle* gives "Error:type name is not allowed"

Comment: @Phirip: No, it's `Circle_getRadius(_this)`, or with the cast it's `Circle_getRadius(static_cast<Circle*>(this))`. (But as I said, the latter is a terrible idea.)

Comment: @Phirip: Do what Mats Petersson says.

Comment: `double Circle_area(Shape* _this)
{
 const double PI = 3.1415927;
 double radi = Circle_getRadius(_this);
 return PI *  radi * radi;
}` gives an error "Error: argument of type "Shape*" is incompatible with parameter of type "Circle*"

Answer (score 1):

```
double radi = Circle_getRadius;
```

should be

```
double radi = Circle_getRadius(_this);
//                                                    ^^^^^^^
```

You've forgotten to call the function.

Comment: Which would lead to an error because `Shape` is probably not a `Circle`.

Answer (score 1):

```
 double radi = Circle_getRadius;
```

is not a function call, you have to specify parameters to pass to the callee function.

```
double radi = Circle_getRadius(_this); //assume Shape is subclass of circle
```